# com.android.ant.NewSetupTask not found error after upgrade to SDK v20 tools

Tags: ant, sdk

After upgrading to the v20 SDK tools, I am receiving this error when attempting to run my Ant build.

The sdk.dir property is correct and verified (adding  to output in build.xml).  Unpacking anttasks.jar it seems that the NewSetupTask is truly missing in the latest tools.

```
META-INF/
META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
com/
com/android/
com/android/ant/
com/android/ant/RenderScriptTask.class
com/android/ant/SingleDependencyTask$1.class
com/android/ant/PropertyByReplaceTask.class
com/android/ant/BuildTypedTask.class
com/android/ant/AaptExecTask$1.class
com/android/ant/AaptExecTask$ResFolderInputPath.class
com/android/ant/AaptExecTask$NoCompress.class
com/android/ant/ApkBuilderTask.class
com/android/ant/GetLibraryPathTask.class
com/android/ant/InputPath.class
com/android/ant/RenderScriptTask$OptLevel.class
com/android/ant/TaskHelper.class
com/android/ant/XPathTask.class
com/android/ant/ManifestMergerTask.class
com/android/ant/DependencyHelper$LibraryProcessor.class
com/android/ant/CheckEnvTask.class
com/android/ant/RenderScriptTask$1.class
com/android/ant/ApkBuilderTask$SourceFolderInputPath.class
com/android/ant/DependencyHelper$JarProcessor$1.class
com/android/ant/ComputeDependencyTask.class
com/android/ant/SingleInputOutputTask.class
com/android/ant/GetLibraryPathTask$1.class
com/android/ant/RenderScriptTask$RenderScriptProcessor.class
com/android/ant/SignApkTask.class
com/android/ant/DependencyHelper$JarProcessor.class
com/android/ant/SignApkTask$NullZipFilter.class
com/android/ant/DependencyHelper$AdvancedLibraryProcessor.class
com/android/ant/DependencyGraph.class
com/android/ant/ComputeDependencyTask$1.class
com/android/ant/DexExecTask.class
com/android/ant/MultiFilesTask.class
com/android/ant/AidlExecTask$1.class
com/android/ant/DependencyHelper.class
com/android/ant/AidlExecTask.class
com/android/ant/BuildConfigTask.class
com/android/ant/ApkBuilderTask$1.class
com/android/ant/AaptExecTask.class
com/android/ant/SingleDependencyTask.class
com/android/ant/DependencyGraph$1.class
com/android/ant/ZipAlignTask.class
com/android/ant/GetTypeTask.class
com/android/ant/GetEmmaFilterTask.class
com/android/ant/IfElseTask.class
com/android/ant/DependencyGraph$DependencyStatus.class
com/android/ant/AidlExecTask$AidlProcessor.class
com/android/ant/ComputeProjectClasspathTask.class
com/android/ant/SingleDependencyTask$InputPathFactory.class
com/android/ant/GetTargetTask$1.class
com/android/ant/MultiFilesTask$DisplayType.class
com/android/ant/MultiFilesTask$SourceProcessor.class
com/android/ant/GetProjectPathsTask.class
com/android/ant/SignApkTask$1.class
com/android/ant/GetTargetTask.class
com/android/ant/ComputeDependencyTask$2.class
com/android/ant/GetLibraryPathTask$LeafProcessor.class
anttasks.properties
```

Where'd it go?

Comment: Good catch! [You might want to put the answer in the Answer field and accept it.]

Answer (score 7):

The problem stems from the fact that I am using a fully customized build.xml file. As such, it contains the following custom ant task definitions:

```
<taskdef name="setup"
    classname="com.android.ant.NewSetupTask"
    classpathref="android.antlibs" />

<taskdef name="aapt"
    classname="com.android.ant.AaptExecTask"
    classpathref="android.antlibs" />

<taskdef name="aidl"
    classname="com.android.ant.AidlExecTask"
    classpathref="android.antlibs" />

<taskdef name="renderscript"
    classname="com.android.ant.RenderScriptTask"
    classpathref="android.antlibs" />

<taskdef name="dex"
    classname="com.android.ant.DexExecTask"
    classpathref="android.antlibs" />

<taskdef name="apkbuilder"
    classname="com.android.ant.ApkBuilderTask"
    classpathref="android.antlibs" />

<taskdef name="zipalign"
    classname="com.android.ant.ZipAlignTask"
    classpathref="android.antlibs" />

<taskdef name="xpath"
    classname="com.android.ant.XPathTask"
    classpathref="android.antlibs" />

<taskdef name="if"
    classname="com.android.ant.IfElseTask"
    classpathref="android.antlibs" />
```

One or more of these are no longer provided by the `anttasks.jar` library. In comparing my build.xml file with the one located `{sdk.dir}/tools/ant/build.xml` I notice that these definitions have been replaced with the following:

```
<taskdef resource="anttasks.properties" classpathref="android.antlibs" />
```

Replacing the old task defs. in my build.xml file with this new task def statement removes the reference to missing tasks and fixes my problem.

Comment: To add a little more details, this is the good thing to do (i was also going from a SDK v20 to v22 with a fully customized build.xml ANT file), but also, you need to modify the android.antlibs path element, since some JARs have been renamed under the {sdk.dir}/tools/lib path, the name is now {sdk.dir}/tools/lib/ant-tasks.jar

Answer (score 2):

Check your anttask.jar under `android-sdks\tools\lib`.

On your `build.xm`l , it might be `anttask.jar` but new sdk its name is `ant-task.jar`.
So, change the name on xml or filesystem.

Comment: Thank you for this nswer, it helped me in similar, but not exact problem.

Answer (score 0):

Using the updated build.xml under [ANDROID_HOME]\android-sdk\tools\ant, you don't need to add the custom ant task definitions

Comment: Yes, that is true if your build.xml imports [ANDROID_HOME]\android-sdk\tools\ant\build.xml.  However, if you've fully customized your build.xml file chances are you don't import this file so you need to update the task defs. appropriately.